# Estimate the risk of swaptions

Tags: risk, swaps, swaption

I would like to model OTM Swaptions. I can use some implementation of the Bachelier model (not B76 due to negative rates) and implied volatilities from Bloomberg.

For 10Y X 10Y (10 years option maturity, 10 years swap length) and 100 bps OTM I get something like 100% volatility pa for the EUR.

I would like to make this number plausible. Does it make sense to use a delta normal method here? Thus apply 
$$
\sigma \approx \Delta \times \text{vola(rate}) \times f 
$$
where $f$ should be some leverage factor. Which rate would I use? What if I look at duration and put
$$
\sigma \approx D \times \text{vola(rate}),
$$
again which rate?

Are there comparable numbers on the web or in Bloomberg? I can not estimate the volatility of swaptions in PORT, right?